# How to stop the running process in a script

Tags: shell-script, process, busybox

newbie here.

I have a IP phone running busybox

I have obtained a script from the devs named avconv that can capture what is happening on the screen of the phone and to run it I use the following command

```
/data/avconv -f fbdev -r 25 -i /dev/fb0 /tmp/output.avi
```

When I m finished I hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to stop the script.

Now I wanted to create a script that would run this command and then copy the output video to my tftp server. So I wrote the following which names the FileName with a date then runs the command and then the intention was to wait 5 seconds, find the pid (chop it to just keep the process ID), kill it and then send the FileName to my tftp..then delete the file..

```
FN=WE34_$(date +%Y%m%d-%H%M%S).avi
/data/avconv -f fbdev -r 25 -i /dev/fb0 /tmp/$FN
sleep 5
pid=`ps | grep avconv`
pidchopped=`echo $pid | cut -d' ' -f 1`
kill -5 $pidchopped
tftp -pl /tmp/$FN -r $FN 192.168.1.50
rm -f /tmp/$FN
```

the problem is that the command in the 2nd line of the script does not stop to to execute the rest of my  script..could you please help me..any tip/hint/input will be highly appreciated..thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you just need to run `avconv` in the background, rather than waiting for it, so the rest of your script can continue. Is that what you're looking for?

To do that, try adding `&` to the end of that line, like so:

```
/data/avconv -f fbdev -r 25 -i /dev/fb0 /tmp/$FN &
```

Comment: it worked Tim Perry
Thanks a lot

Comment: i m sure there are smarter ways to run it and kill it but it works now when running in the background!!! thanks again